# Collating a Collection from Multiple Unknown Objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario where I have a root type that many, many, many objects in my project implement as a collection, like so...

```
class Page {
  // ... 
}
interface IPages{
  IList<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

And then there are dozens of objects, almost everything in the project has a collection of `Page`.

What I need to do is to get all of the `Page` objects all the way down the structure tree from a root object. However this can be very abstract, and knowing exactly what will exist is difficult. A simple 'foreach' loop doesn't seem appropriate for it...

Is there any way to start from one object, and examine everything in it to see if it has an interface, and if so, pull the appropriate data out into a master collection, recursively?

Comment: are you looking to flatten the entire hierarchy, or are you looking for specific instances of `T` where `T : Page` in the hierarchy?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure... but it sounds like flattening the entire hierarchy is what I am after. I basically add things to the 'root' object, and the pages contain the data on how to alter it, so I need to be able to pull that data and do the appropriate calculations and save the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell, since Page doesn't appear to implement IPages in your example.

Depending on your implementation, this extension method might work...

```
public static IEnumerable<Page> GetDescendantsAndSelf(this IPages root)
{
  if(root == null)
    yield break;  // the Page doesn't implement IPages
  if(root is Page)  // the IPages is actually a Page
    yield return root as Page;
  // go through each child
  // call this method recursively and return the result
  foreach(var child in root.Pages)
    foreach(var page in child.GetDescendantsAndSelf())
      yield return page;
}
```

Comment: `yield return this as Page` should be `yield return root as Page`; also the extension method should be static (and reside in a static class)

Comment: @jeroenh: derp.  thanks; its not actually C#, its *C#-like pseudocode*.

Comment: It's the 'go through each child' part I'm kind of having trouble with. It's not possible to know what the children will always be.

Comment: @Ciel: Are you looking for children of a specific type?

Comment: No, I am looking for all children. Some may implement the interface, some may not. It is difficult to know at code time.

Comment: @Ciel: Last question (and I'll edit)--are all the children being returned Pages, or can they be different types?

Comment: They can be any type, the only ones I am interested in are the ones that inherit `IPage`, but not everything does - sometimes the object needed is multiple levels deep.

Comment: @Ciel: Crap, this is getting more convoluted.  Page implements IPage all the time, right?  And sometimes it implements IPages, right?  But other things can implement IPages, right?  So you want to browse the tree of IPages implementors, and pull out all IPage instances you find.  Do I have this correct?

Comment: `IPage` is an interface that has an `IList<Page>`, multiple objects implement `IPage` but not all objects must, but the root object must be able to retrieve all `Page` objects in its entire hierarchy.

Comment: @Ciel: So there is no `IPages`.  "multiple objects implement" but the only way your question makes sense is if some `Page`s do.  Is that the case?

Comment: There is an `IPages`. Everything that implements `IPages` must have `IList<Page>`, but not all objects implement `IPage`, however I need to go all the way down the entire hierarchy and get every object that does, and it is not always possible to tell at code time what this may be like.

Comment: I basically need to be able to iterate every property of every class and drill down through it.

Comment: It seems as though I need to rethink my approach. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ciel: Sorry I couldn't give you a simple answer.  Definitely a code smell; your approach can only benefit from a little redesign.

Comment: @Ciel: Now you do; the problems you had with this issue is a code smell.  As in, "this smells funny, something is wrong here but I can't quite put my finger on it."